# How to feed information from one webpage into a view django

Tags: python, django

So, it has been two days now of searching StackOverflow for an answer, but I can't seem to find one that fits my question. Mainly, I think this question stems from a lack of understanding of how URLs pass information to views.

What I want is when a user clicks on the pdf link, the application should grab the client's name, zip code, and city and feed that information into a pdf. (pdf is kind of auxiliary, I am mainly just trying to figure out how to extract information from one page and feed it into a view).

Note: I wish I could imbed a picture here, but can't without a reputation of 10. You will get a great idea of what I am trying to accomplish by the picture.
[click here to see my demo client page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoFsS.png)

Below is my best attempt on how I can see this working, but I obviously don't know how to actually do it.

```html
    #client_detail.html

    {% extends "base_generic.html" %}

    {% block content %}
      <h1>Client: {{ compuweatherclient.client }}</h1>

      <p><strong>City:</strong> {{ compuweatherclient.city }}</p>
      <p><strong>State:</strong> {{ compuweatherclient.state }}</p>
      <p><strong>Zipcode:</strong> {{ compuweatherclient.zipcode }}</p>

      <a href="{% url 'catalog:renderpdf' var1=compuweatherclient.client %}">PDF</a>

    {% endblock %}
```

```py
    #views.py
    class ClientDetailView(generic.DetailView):
      
        model = CompuWeatherClient
        
    def renderpdf(request, var1):
        # deleted a lot here for the sake of simplicity. 
        dosomethingwithvar1(var1)

        return response
```

```py
    #urls.py
    urlpatterns += [
        path('pdf/', views.renderpdf, name='renderpdf'),
        path('client/<int:pk>', views.ClientDetailView.as_view(), name='client-detail'),


    ]
```

So yeah, how do I do this? Any links to other problems or examples would be extremely helpful.

EDIT

Perhaps I am thinking about the workflow wrong. It dawned on me that the detail view is able to display the client information already. Why would I need to use a GET method to extract information that I already have? Maybe, the pdf function belongs in the detail class....

Comment: So when people click on the PDF on your page, you just want the same details that were on the page, displayed in the PDF?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah. After I get this working, I'll connect it to some data and feed data tables into it with another function in the view. But that might be out of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it, you can't pass the data via GET method ?
How about using session to store data? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: maybe? My problem with it GET is when I click on the pdf link, it redirects to another URL defined in urls.py, thus losing the page characteristics that I want to access. I would prefer this not to happen, but I'm not savvy enough with Django yet to configure that option.

Comment: I dont get it... is it not in request.GET.get('var1') ?

Answer (score 0):

So, I think you should use reportlab, you just need to `pip install reportlab io` For more information and functions with reportlab, [here is reportlab documentation](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf) and [here is a small tutorial on how to use it with django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/outputting-pdf/)

```py
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from django.http import FileResponse
import io

def renderpdf(request, var1):
   # try something like this
   buffer = io.BytesIO()
   p = canvas.Canvas(buffer)
   p.drawString(100, 100, f'The city is {var1.city}')
   p.drawString(100, 150, f'The state is {var1.state}')
   p.drawString(100, 200, f'The zipcode is {var1.zipcode}')
   p.showpage()
   p.save()
   buffer.seek(0)
   return FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=True, filename=f'{var1.client}.pdf')
```

Comment: I think you are one step too far. I'm interested in how to get var1 into the function.

Answer (score 0):

So, I am answering my own question. While I do not know exactly what was wrong with my html templates, something was. I ended up ditching reportlab and found this helpful video describing how to make a pdf using xhtml2pdf.

After, editing my htmls like the video, I was able to get my issue resolved.
[1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3MuH6xaDjI&feature=emb_logo&ab_channel=Pyplane